# jQuery and Js functions syntax mixing

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have small problem with the following. This is ofc just a snippet of the whole code and it is usually run through a setInterval(time,function); command but I'd like to replace the auto-sliding pictures by having instead a "next" button, why can't I just use jQuery and stick it into a

```
$("#nextBtn").click(nextSlide);
```

command ? I get my button appearing but no event. Could it be that I'm putting the jQuery command in a JS

```
function onLoadWindow(e) {}
```

instead of jQuery's

```
$(document).ready(function() {})
```

I just finished learning the basics of JS recently and started jQ shortly after, so I'm still a beginner in both but with some prior programming experience with Java. I'm kinda new to mixing syntax's together. Thanks a bunch for the help! =)

EDIT : replaced code snippet with full code. I tried skimming it by taking out what wasn't needed like a couple tags and relevant styling. But now it seems I can't even get the div button to send text to console so Im pretty sure there's an obvious "noob" error somewhere, sorry for "wasting" people's time ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
           <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JS Slideshow</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

            .slide {
                height:200px;
                width:320px;
                position:absolute;
                opacity:0;
            }

            img {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }   

            #slideshow {
                position:relative;
            }

            .active {
                opacity:1;
                transition:opacity 1s;
            }

            #nextBtn {
                display:block;
                float:left;
                height:25px;
                width:40px;
                background-color:black;
                margin-top:210px;
            }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            window.addEventListener("load",onLoadWindow);

            var active_slide;
            var slides;

            function onLoadWindow(e) {
                var slideShow=document.getElementById("slideshow");
                slides=slideShow.getElementsByTagName("div");
                active_slide=0;

                slides[0].classList.add("active");

                //setInterval(nextSlide,10000);
                $("nextBtn").click(nextSlide);

            }

            function nextSlide () {
                slides[active_slide].classList.remove("active");
                active_slide++;

                active_slide%=3;  

                slides[active_slide].classList.add("active");
            }


        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="slideshow">

            <div class="slide">
                <img src="IMG/bridge.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            </div>

            <div class="slide">
                <img src="IMG/leaf.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            </div>

            <div class="slide">
                <img src="IMG/road.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            </div>
</div>
    <div id="nextBtn"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does the `nextSlide` function work when you call it manually from the console?

Comment: You need to show the overall structure of your code: where is that "click" handler setup code?  Where is the "nextSlide" function declared?

Comment: Also it's all the same syntax - jQuery is just a JavaScript library that adds functionality without extending syntax at all.

Comment: In the future, show us all of your code.

Comment: youre missing the hash bang in the selector. ` $("nextBtn").click(nextSlide)` is suppose to be ` $("#nextBtn").click(nextSlide)` right?

Comment: check if  your onLoadWindow function is actually executed, rest looks ok

Comment: this is the part where you feel like typing "!"#(%/#(%"#%*Å"OP#%)="#(%)=" from frustration ... all that trouble i went through, prior to finally posting here to finally find out it was, as always, one missing char, of course. Plus Im doubly angry at myself because those are one of the first things I learned.. addressing the css selectors right. Thanks a lot everyone! Sorry for wasting web space with this :p

Comment: should I flag this for deletion?

Answer (score 2):

it was indeed just a missing hash symbol to correctly refer to the Id .. thanks to all and of course VeXii for pointing it out x)